# Finding a Solution to a linear Voltera equation of the second type

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following integral equation:

$$
u(t) = 
\int_t^T a(s) ds + \int_t^T b(s)u(s) ds ,
$$

with $a, b, u$ being functions from $[t,T] \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $. I transformed the integral equation into the following differential equation by using Leibniz' rule:

$$
u'(t) = -a(t) - b(t)u(t).
$$

Using the explanation on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) I derived the following solution to the differential equation:

$$
u(t) = - \dfrac{\int_t^T \exp[-\int_t^s b(u) du ] a(s) ds + c }{ \exp[-\int_t^s b(u) du ]}
$$

Unfortunately, I think this solution is not correct. By being told the solution of a similar integral equation, I guess the solution to the integral equation above is:

$$ 
u(t) = \int_t^T a(s) \exp \left( \int_t^s b(u) du \right) ds 
$$

However, I don't know how to verify my guessed solution to the integral equation and I don't know how to obtain this guess without exploiting knowledge of a similar problem. Additionally, I don't know why my solution of the differential equation does not match the guessed solution.

Can somebody kindly point out some steps to solve the original integral equation and how to verify it's solution?

P.S. I would also very much like to know the name for the class of integral equation the one above belongs to. I couldn't associate the integral equation above with what I've read about them in general.

Comment: It is a [linear Volterra equation of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation) where the kernel does not depend on $t$, which makes it easier to solve by differentiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using integrating factor gives (I replace the integration variable $u$ with $\tau$)
$$
\left[u(t)\exp\int_T^t b(\tau)\,d\tau\right]'=-a(t)\exp\int_T^t b(\tau)\,d\tau\ \Rightarrow \ 
u(t)=\frac{\int_t^T a(s)\exp\int_T^s b(\tau)\,d\tau\,ds+c}{\exp\int_T^t b(\tau)\,d\tau}.
$$
Two exponential functions can be glued to one
$$
\frac{\exp\int_T^s b(\tau)\,d\tau}{\exp\int_T^t b(\tau)\,d\tau}=\exp\left(\int_T^s+\int_t^T\right)=\exp\int_t^s b(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
and the constant $c=0$ due to $u(T)=0$ which gives
$$
u(t)=\int_t^Ta(s)\exp\int_t^s b(\tau)\,d\tau\,ds.
$$
P.S. Your first attempt is *almost* right, but you got mixed up with the variables.